# Sum of a sequence that has an answer, but I can't get that answer by hand

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find n if

$a_1 = 4$

$r = -4$

$S_n = 13108$

Using the formula

$S_n = \frac{a_1(1 - (r)^n)}{1 - r}$ I would have

$13108 = \frac{4(1 - (-4)^n)}{5}$

$65540 = 4(1 - (-4)^n)$

$16385 = 1 - (-4)^n$

$16384 = -(-4)^n$

$-16384 = (-4)^n$

I can't take the log now though because I have negatives! I know the answer is 7 because if I plug in n = 7, I do get the desired result. However, I'm not sure how to get this by hand. Can someone please clear this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{split}-16384&=(-4)^n\\
16384&=(-1)^{n-1}4^n \text{     (equation 2)}
\end{split}$$

At this point there will be a solution if for the $n$ such that $4^n=16384$, we have that $(-1)^{n-1}$ is just $1$. In terms of integer solutions, there would be a solution if $4^n=16384$ for some odd $n$. We focus on $n=\frac{\log 16384}{\log 4}=7$, and verify that this indeed works in the original equation as $(-1)^{7-1}=1$ so the lhs and rhs are equal in equation 2. If instead $n$ were some even integer such that $4^n=16384$, there would be no solution due to the sign mismatch.

Comment: That is clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We know that $-16384 = (-4)^n$. Taking the absolute values of both sides, we conclude that $16384 = 4^n$. We then take $\log_4$ of both sides to get that $n = 7$.

We must check that $n = 7$ actually gives us the correct value of $S_n$ by plugging $n$ back into the formula (otherwise, there could be no solutions). Thankfully, it does.

Comment: WHy are we taking the absolute value? it seems to come out of no where

Comment: @DominicBlanco If the problem is the existence of negative numbers, it makes sense to get rid of the negative numbers. The canonical way of getting rid of negative numbers is by taking the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

$$-16348=(-4)^n \implies n=2p+1$$

$$\implies -16384=-(-4)^{2p}$$

$$\implies 16384=(16)^p$$

$$p=\frac{\ln(16384)}{\ln(16)}=3$$
$$\implies n=7$$

Comment: You said n = 2p + 1. So why did you write it as -(-4)^2p? I don't understand

Comment: @DominicBlanco but the LHS is $ - 16384$